# What is openwall crypt_r's data parameter?

Tags: c, crypt

`char *crypt_r(const char *key, const char *setting, void *data)`

What is one supposed to pass as data argument? I can't find the docs for this. The Linux version uses the `crypt_data` type but that's not available in this header.

http://www.openwall.com/crypt/

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky interface because it wants to allocate and then recycle an opaque-to-the-caller buffer of opaque-to-the-caller size, which is not something that is easy in C.

If I'm reading the [OpenWall `crypt(3)` manpage](http://www.openwall.com/crypt/openwall-crypt.3.pdf) (PDF) correctly, you *should* be able to get the `crypt_data` struct declared by defining `_GNU_SOURCE` before including any system headers (not just before including `crypt.h`).  Or, you could use `crypt_ra`, something like this.  (Note: C++ `<string>` and `<vector>` used to avoid a bunch of tedious memory allocation cruft which would obscure the important parts of the example.  Crash-on-failure behavior for the same reason.  Not tested at all; not even compiled.)

```
#define _OW_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

void crypt_many(vector<string> &encrypted,
                vector<string> const &passwords,
                const char *setting)
{
    void *buffer = 0;
    int bufsiz = 0;

    encrypted.clear();
    encrypted.reserve(passwords.size());
    for (auto p = passwords.begin(), limit = passwords.end();
         p != limit; p++)
    {
        char *enc = crypt_ra(p->c_str(), setting, &buffer, &bufsiz);
        if (!enc) abort();
        encrypted.push_back(string(enc));
    }

    free(buffer);
}
```

On the first call to `crypt_ra`, it allocates some amount of memory using `malloc` and stashes it in `buffer` (and the size in `bufsiz`), and does some precomputation, whose results are saved in `buffer`; the returned `enc` pointer also points in there.  On subsequent calls, it reuses the space and the precomputed tables, and it may resize the buffer if it notices it's not big enough (this is why the buffer size is an argument).  You, the caller, don't touch `buffer` or `bufsiz` at all, except that it is your responsibility to free `buffer` when you're done using `crypt_ra`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same setting / salt for multiple passwords should you?

Comment: @XTF I *think* it will generate a new random salt for each password if you supply only an algorithm-selection code in the "setting" string, but I could have misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: AFAIK `setting` should come from `crypt_gensalt()` and the random bits come from its `input` parameter.